# How to create a clone of an array through generic wildcard capture in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am seeking to implement a generic class which has two fields:

```
class A<E>{
    private final E[] values;
    private final int size;
    //default constructor
    public A(){
        values = (E[]) new Object[0];
        size = 0;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to introduce a copy constructor which replicates an generic A object of an unknown type. Something like this:

```
class A<E>{
    private final E[] values;
    private final int size;
    //default constructor
    public A(){
        values = (E[]) new Object[0];
        size = 0;
    }

    //the copy constructor
    public A(A<?> a){
        //Code here
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to use a wildcard capture helper function as

```
private <T> T[] copyHelper(A<T> originalA){
    T[] originalValue = originalA.value;
    T[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(originalValue, 0);
    return copy;
}
```

and then in the copy constructor do

```
public A(A<?> a){
    value = (A[]) copyHelper(a);
    size = a.size;
}
```

Does this serve the purpose? Isn't casting the return value from `copyHelper()` to `E[]` superfluous? 
How else can I achieve a copy of the passed `A<?>` object, whose type is unknown?

Comment: You shouldn't be copying an instance over that doesn't exactly match the type you want.  `A<?>` seems wrong in preference to `A<E>`.

Comment: How then, should I go about implementing a copy constructor in case the user wants to instantiate the class with an object of an different type(different generic class) - a class other than `E`?

Comment: I think that would be an excellent question to ask.  You should probably post again.

Comment: I don't think the wildcard is the right idea either. What would you expect `new A<Integer>(new A<String>())` to do for example? The wildcard allows you to do that. Also capture doesn't quite work this way.

Comment: @Radiodef: How about new `A<Object>(new A<Integer>())`?

Comment: Then you should take a look at the answer from @chiastic-security (`<? extends E>`).

Comment: OK, but it's common in mathematics and other sciences to regard statements which may be false as false.  One exception dooms the conclusion.  So generics will look at the case Radiodef mentioned and declare your assignment unworkable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the passed in instance is of type `A<E>`, in which case you can copy it, or it's not, in which case you can't copy it into an instance of type `A<E>`. There's therefore no point in allowing `A<?>` as the type of the input: you should restrict it to `A<E>`.

Actually you might restrict it to `A<? extends E>`, because these are still compatible with `E`.

Trying to replicate anything else into here isn't meaningful, any more than a `HashSet` constructor can take a copy parameter of type `int[]`.